# change fcm notification sound flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to change the sound of the notification from fcm and added the file in the assets and change the sound in the api but still no change in the sound and added the permission of the notification and added the file in path android\app\src\main\res\raw

here is the code for the fire base notification it work and display sound with the default sound

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';



final AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

Future<void> handelBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)async{
  print('title ${remoteMessage.notification?.title}');
  print('body ${remoteMessage.notification?.body}');
  print('date ${remoteMessage.data}');
  print('sound${remoteMessage.notification?.android?.sound}');
  if(remoteMessage.notification?.android?.sound=='beeper_alert'){
     await _playCustomSound(); 
  }

}
Future<void> _playCustomSound() async {
  try {
    // Load and play the custom sound file from assets
    await _audioPlayer.play('assets/beeper_alert.mp3' as Source,);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error playing custom sound: $e');
  }
}

class FirebaseAPI{
  final firebaseMessaging=FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future<String?> initNotification()async{
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    final FCMToken = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('the token $FCMToken');
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handelBackgroundMessage);
    
    return FCMToken;
  }
}
```

here is the main

```
void main() async{
  setupServiceLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAPI().initNotification();

  
}
```

here is the mainifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application
        android:label="flutter_application_1"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the post man when i send the it

```
{
    "to" : "my token",
    "notification": {
        "title": "you have recieved a message from tester",
        "body": "testing body from post man",
        "sound": "beeper_alert"
    },
    "android": {
        "priority": "HIGH"
       
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "order",
        "id": "87",
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    }
}
```